# How to Use Emoji's In unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, textmeshpro

I want to use the Emoji's in my project. but as we all know that unity is not supporting the all emoji's. First I try to make the Sprite asset and with it I can use many emoji but the Emoji's with the complex Unicode like "1f3c3_1f3fb_200d_2642" this Emoji.

I want to use all the Emoji's in unity Using the TextMeshPro.
Is there any way to make it happen in unity.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a font that contains that emoji?

Comment: I used the Two Approaches.

Comment: 1- I use the Images in the texture packer importer to make the sprite atlas and json file of the Selected Emoji's. the use this to make the sprite asset in the Unity and used this but unity Didn't handle the Complex Unicode.

Comment: 2- I used the Apple Emoji font to that unity has introduce the Emojis in text mesh pro 3.2.0-pre.4. but id is still not working with the all emoji's I contacted with the Team and they said they are Working on it.

Comment: You can also use SVGs. @RahmatAli

Comment: I look like Pretty Dumb to Ask But Will you explain this?

Comment: Unity has a package that allows SVGs to be imported into Unity UI Toolkit. if you don't know about SVG refer to [Fireship Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emFMHH2Bfvo&pp=ygUKc3ZnIHZzIHBuZw%3D%3D)]. I think it works for normal UI too.

Comment: I am getting your Point but and I am using it in my game but the Unity cannot Understand the Complex Unicode. but the Simple Emoji like Face and fruit animals are Working fine but the Emoji's like flag and Skinned emoji has the Complex Unicode which is Difficult for unity to understand it now.

Comment: It is not the Image Format Issue the Unity is not Able to Under the Complex Unicode. Thanks for Your Concern on this.

Comment: What is the font you are using emoji font?

Comment: I am using the Apple Emoji Font. I downloaded it from the Google.

Comment: Try this font:
[Noto Emoji](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji/glyphs)

Comment: I have Tried this one But it didn't show Anything. it shows only the Blank Input Field.

Comment: I have [an enumerator class](https://gist.github.com/geniuszxy/9bb507f03eb17526d4f58f3c387031b3) that can extract emoji sequences from a string, you can use it to replace emoji sequences to sprite names which TMP supports.

Comment: Ok Thanks, @shingo
But will you explain this a little more to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should prepare your sprite asset first, here is an example that uses the [`EmojiIterator`](https://gist.github.com/geniuszxy/9bb507f03eb17526d4f58f3c387031b3) class to convert long emoji sequences to TMP's sprite tags.

```
static string ProcessText(string text)
{
    var itor = new EmojiIterator(text);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(itor.MoveNext())
    {
        if(itor.SequenceLength <= 2) //TMP can handle single emoji characters.
            sb.Append(itor.Sequence);
        else //use sprite asset
            sb.Append($@"<sprite name=""{ConvertToName(itor.Sequence)}"">"
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The `ConvertToName` method is used to convert a string like `"\U0001f3c3\U0001f3fb\u200d\u2642"` to `"1f3c3_1f3fb_200d_2642"`.

```
static string ConvertToName(string text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var j = char.ConvertToUtf32(text, i);
        if (j > 0xffff)
            i++;
        sb.Append(j.ToString("x"));
        sb.Append('_');
    }
    return sb.Length > 0 ? sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1) : "";
}
```

Comment: The StringBuilder() is not in the EmojiIterato?

Comment: `StringBuilder` is a .net class.

Comment: I have tried your Approach, when I try to Write the Single character it works Fine but when I try to press the Emoji from keyboard it Stuck in Infinite Loop(While Loop).

This is the Image link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eXPEOLV1QDkpNkUuA8Q9Pqe3ebiIJOat

Comment: Please try to copy the class again, the code is outdated and I've updated it.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the Late Response but there are Some Emoji's which is Not Working with this Approach,

Comment: I have Accepted the Answer but there is Some Issue Will you help? Like the flag's The Flag just show the Yellow Question Mark Image when clicked on the Flag.

Comment: What does "clicked on the Flag" mean? Do you know the emoji sequence of the flag? Was it found by the iterator?

Comment: Sorry for issue. Resolved it by myself I named the Emoji with the Unicode like "1f4gf-1fdhf" but In your Script the Name Shows of the Emoji is "1f4gf_1fdhf", there is the "_" so that's why it cannot get the name resolved it by my side.

Comment: Will yo response on this thread Also thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801039/how-to-set-the-glyph-by-value-of-sprite-asset-of-all-unity

Comment: Hi Shingo, I am facing the Issue in which there are some Emoji's which have the name like"00ae_fe0f" and "26a0_fe0f", Your Component Could not get the name of these Emoji's. there are About 300 plus emoji's with this Unicode. I appreciate your Help from the Start. here's the reference Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mirS0DTRqNHQUxlA5i7kq5ouhJk8TZh0/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hi @shingo Thanks for your Help In past Regarding Emoji's Is there Any Update Regarding this.

Comment: No, haven't you used the TMP built-in emoji solution?

Comment: Ok thank If you find or I Find the Solution to this Issue Let each other Know.